# setter and getter does not work

Tags: python-2.7, setter, getter

I used the following code:

```
class P:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value * 2

p = P()
print(p.x)
p.x = 10
print(p.x)
```

`output:
 None
 10`

The output should be:
`None
20`

I want to know why this does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's why:

> ```
> class P:
> ```

Descriptors only work in ***new-style classes***.

```
class P(object):
```